# when i try to submit a form its is showing TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, react-context

this is my simple book-list application using react context API. I have created a context to addBook, removeBook, and entire Book state and provide to other components.
when I try to add a book via a form it shows `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

below is my book context where I have created a context for addBook, removeBook, and entire BookState and provided it to its wrapping child components

**BookContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import  {uuid}  from 'uuid/dist/v1';

export const BookContext = createContext();

const BookContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: 'name of wind', author: 'Elizabath' },
    { id: 2, title: 'the narrow bridge', author: 'Mc clary' },
  ]);
 const addBook = (title, author) => {
    setBooks([...books, {  id: uuid(),title, author }])
  };
 const removeBook = (id) => {
    setBooks(books.filter((book) => book.id !== id))
  };
  return (
    <BookContext.Provider
      value={{ books, addBook, removeBook }}
    >
      {children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default BookContextProvider;
```

below is my bookForm.js file where I have consumed context from the provider and destructured addBook from it
**BookForm.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { BookContext } from '../Contexts/BookContext';

function BookForm() {
  const { addBook } = useContext(BookContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addBook(title, author)
    setTitle('')
    setAuthor('')
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Book Name"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Author Name"
        value={author}
        onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" value="add Book" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default BookForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be working fine. I believe the issue lies in a separate part. I'd suggest following the stack trace of the error as that should give you a better location of the error. Or there's more to the context provider than you included on this.

There might be another component that uses the books that are added that throws when a new book is added.

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useState } = React;
const uuid = uuidv1;
const BookContext = createContext();

const BookContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: "name of wind", author: "Elizabath" },
    { id: 2, title: "the narrow bridge", author: "Mc clary" },
  ]);
  const addBook = (title, author) => {
    setBooks([...books, { id: uuid(), title, author }]);
  };
  const removeBook = (id) => {
    setBooks(books.filter((book) => book.id !== id));
  };
  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, addBook, removeBook }}>
      {children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
};

function BookForm() {
  const { addBook } = useContext(BookContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addBook(title, author);
    setTitle("");
    setAuthor("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Book Name"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Author Name"
        value={author}
        onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" value="add Book" />
    </form>
  );
}

function Books() {
  const { books } = useContext(BookContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {books.map(({ id, title, author }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          {title} - {author}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BookContextProvider>
    <BookForm />
    <Books />
  </BookContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uuid/8.3.2/uuidv1.min.js" integrity="sha512-4hJwRX3o1o5dU3A+ffhCQpLzOT7U0wDoR9Ha7McoxXez011iFJ6RMB08BrzE23G+gB3gNriotihq7TPIf7x/NA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="root" />
```